# Integral of the natural logarithm of a function

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I solve this?
$$
\int \ln(f(x)) dx = ?
$$
I know that
$$
\int \ln(x) dx = x\ln(x) - x
$$

In particular, I am interested in

$$
\int \ln\left(\frac{1}{a^2 x^2}\right) dx
$$

Comment: That integral may not always a have closed form. Take $f(x) = x^2+x$ as an example.

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain okay I will go a bit more practical then! I've updated my question

Comment: Note that in your case, $$\ln \frac{1}{a^2x^2} = -2\ln a -2\ln x$$assuming $a,x>0$.

Comment: Using basic properties of the logarithm, we see that the integrand is actually equal to $-2(\ln(ax))$. Can you integrate that?

Comment: @GoodMorningCaptain : I think you can integrate that one:
$$\int\ln(x^2+x)\;dx = \int(\ln x + \ln(x+1))\;dx = \int\ln x\;dx + \int\ln u \; du = \cdots$$ where $u = x+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** *[Converted from comment]* Note that in your case, $$\ln \frac{1}{a^2x^2} = -2\ln a -2\ln x$$
assuming $a,x>0$.